# Query: Data&Time Max group B

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data and I need to derive the max date (date and time) A for group B in google sheets.

```
A                       B
09/02/2023, 11:37:44    MARIO
09/02/2023, 11:42:41    MARIO
09/02/2023, 11:48:03    LUCA
09/02/2023, 13:03:06    LUCA
09/02/2023, 13:08:24    MARIO
09/02/2023, 13:15:57    LUCA
09/02/2023, 13:20:25    MARIO
09/02/2023, 13:23:38    MARIO
09/02/2023, 13:30:01    MARIO
09/02/2023, 13:33:36    LUCA
09/02/2023, 13:38:41    LUCA
09/02/2023, 13:41:38    LUCA
09/02/2023, 13:58:50    LUCA
09/02/2023, 14:04:57    LUCA

OUTPUT
09/02/2023, 13:30:01    MARIO
09/02/2023, 14:04:57    LUCA
```

**=Query**(Dati!A1:M,"Select B, Max(A) where B <> '' group by B label max(A) ''",0)

No MAX

Comment: Please refrain from putting tags in the title. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the commas before running the QUERY:

```
=ArrayFormula(Query({SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,",",),B1:B},"Select Col2, Max(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''",0))
```

Comment: Sorry, the query works, but I don't
select the last date due to the time, although the time is decisive.

Comment: Col1 is not date